# Dart converting String to Array then compare two array

Tags: dart

I'm trying to convert strings to arrays then compare two arrays. If the same value needs to remove from both array. Then finally merge two arrays and find array length. Below is my code

```
  String first_name = "siva";
  String second_name = "lovee";
  List<String> firstnameArray=new List();
  List<String> secondnameArray=new List();
  firstnameArray = first_name.split('');      
  secondnameArray = second_name.split('');
   var totalcount=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < first_name.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < second_name.length; j++) {
      if (firstnameArray[i] == secondnameArray[j]) {
        print(firstnameArray[i] + "" + " == " + secondnameArray[j]);
        firstnameArray.removeAt(i); 
        secondnameArray.removeAt(i); 
        break;

      }
    }
  }
  var finalList = new List.from(firstnameArray)..addAll(secondnameArray);
  print(finalList);
  print(finalList.length);
```

But always getting this error **Unsupported operation: Cannot remove from a fixed-length lis**t can you help me how to fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that **firstnameArray**, **secondnameArray** is not a fixed-length list by initializing it as below:

```
var firstnameArray = new List<String>.from(first_name.split(''));
var secondnameArray= new List<String>.from(second_name.split(''));
```

Thereby declaring **firstnameArray**, **secondnameArray** to be a mutable copy of input.

Comment: Input: String first = 'sivaaa'; String second = 'lovea'; Output: siaaloe Above is my expected output not unique characters. Do you have any idea about that? i changed that line but getting range error.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you are trying to do is to find the length of unique characters in given two strings. Well, the `Set` type is perfect for this use-case. Here's an example of what you can do:

```dart
void main() {
  String first = 'abigail';
  String second = 'allie';

  var unique = '$first$second'.split('').toSet();
  print(unique);
}
```

This would give you an output of:

```
{a, b, i, g, l, e}
```

On which you may perform functions like `.toList()`, or `.where()` or `.length`.

Comment: Input:
  String first = 'sivaaa';
  String second = 'lovea';
  Output:
  siaaloe

  Above is my expected output not unique characters. Do you have any idea about that?